# How can I use a toast of Chakra UI throughout all the components?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to show an alert when user makes any request in my react application. The thing is that currently I am using separate toast components for separate components. How should I use one single toast component throughout the whole application. I tried putting the toast component in `App.jsx` but in order to manage the toast message and color I have to do prop-drilling, which I want to avoid. I am using redux so I can not use `useContext` for managing the toast. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using a higher-order component called **HOC** to wrap the `toast` and provide the necessary props to it. This way, you can keep the toast in a central location and use the **HOC** to wrap other components that need to display the toast.

For example:

```
// withToast.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { ToastProvider } from "@chakra-ui/core";

const withToast = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const [toast, setToast] = useState({
      message: "",
      color: "",
      isOpen: false,
    });

    const showToast = (message, color) => {
      setToast({ message, color, isOpen: true });
    };

    const hideToast = () => {
      setToast({ message: "", color: "", isOpen: false });
    };

    return (
      <ToastProvider>
        <WrappedComponent
          {...props}
          showToast={showToast}
          hideToast={hideToast}
          toast={toast}
        />
      </ToastProvider>
    );
  };
};

export default withToast;
```

Now you can use the same toast in every component that is being wrapped by `withToast`:

```
import React from 'react';
import withToast from './withToast';

const App = (props) => {
  const { showToast, toast } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => showToast("Hello, World!", "green")}>
        Show Toast
      </button>
      <Toast message={toast.message} color={toast.color} isOpen={toast.isOpen} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withToast(App);
```

You can also wrap multiple components in the **HOC** and use the `showToast` and `hideToast` functions in any component that is rendered within the wrapped component, this way you don't have to *prop-drill* `showToast`and `hideToast`.